# Merge using Multiple table sources (User Defined Table Type & Input Parameters)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, upsert

I'm trying to upsert data into a table, called "CustomOrderReqs". I'll insert/update data into this table periodically using User-Defined Table Type & Input Parameters to the Stored proc. I have the final table as follows:

[CustomOrderReqs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDMoS.png)

I have defined a User-Defined Table type to be use in the Upsert Stored Proc, as follows

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CustomOrderRequestsType] AS TABLE(
[Customer_ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Customer_Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Customer_Notes] [nvarchar](Max) NOT NULL ) Go
```

Below is my stored procedure to perform this operation, and it has some errors when I'm trying to use the User-Defined table type and Input parameters, along in the Merge statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpsertCustomDesignReqsTable] 
 @OrderNumber VARCHAR(30)
,@Product_Id VARCHAR(50)
,@Purchase_amt VARCHAR(Max)
,@Details CustomOrderRequestsType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE [dbo].[CustomOrderReqs] AS TARGET
USING (VALUES (@OrderNumber, @Product_Id, ,@Purchase_amt, @Details) ) AS SOURCE  /*** Error Here **/
ON (SOURCE.[@OrderNumber] = TARGET.[Order Number]) 
    AND (SOURCE.[@Product_Id] = TARGET.[Product_Id] 
    AND (SOURCE.[Cutomer_Id] = TARGET.[Customer_Id]))
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.[Order Number] = @OrderNumber,
           TARGET.[Product_Id] = @NegItem,
           TARGET.[Purchase_amt] = @Purchase_amt,
           TARGET.[Customer_ID] = Source.[Customer_ID],
           TARGET.[Customer_Email = Source.[Customer_Email,
           TARGET.[Customer_Notes] = Source.[Customer_Notes]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT VALUES (
                @OrderNumber,
                @NegItem,
                @Purchase_amt,
                Source.[Customer_ID],
                Source.[Customer_Email,
                Source.[Customer_Notes]);
END
```

With the above query, I'm getting an error message on the Source Declaration line and the message is as follows:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_UpsertCustomDesignReqsTable, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@Details"

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Details is a table - you're treating it like a column? Please explain what you are actually trying to do with your line which includes both vars and a table var.

Comment: Thanks for Commenting @DaleK. I'm trying to use the User-Defined Table Type `(@Details)` Column `(Customer_Id)` to verify Match or existing record in the `CustomOrderReqs` table inorder to update, if exists. It is not the only information that is being used, but also using the `@OrderNumber & @Product_Id` columns, outside the `@Details` User-Defined Table Type. You can see the same right above the `WHEN MATCHED THEN` statement in the above proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What add the variables to the merge table? Why not just use them directly.

Also you might find things easier if you solve all your syntax errors first, including defining `@NegItem`.

Its also best practice to explicitly list the columns when inserting.

```
MERGE [dbo].[CustomOrderReqs] AS [TARGET]
USING @Details AS [SOURCE]
ON [SOURCE].OrderNumber = @OrderNumber 
    AND [SOURCE].Product_Id = @Product_Id 
    AND [SOURCE].Cutomer_Id = [TARGET].Customer_Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET
    [TARGET].Customer_ID = [SOURCE].Customer_ID
    , [TARGET].Customer_Email = [SOURCE].Customer_Email
    , [TARGET].Customer_Notes = [SOURCE].Customer_Notes
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (OrderNumber, ProductId, Amount, Customer_Id, Customer_Email, Customer_Notes)
VALUES (@OrderNumber, @Product_Id, @Purchase_amt, [SOURCE].[Customer_ID], [SOURCE].[Customer_Email, [SOURCE].[Customer_Notes]);
```

As you have added a further requirement in the comments to only update when a value has changed consider changing the line `WHEN MATCHED THEN` to

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN AND (
    -- Assume ID is never null
    [SOURCE].Customer_ID <> [TARGET].Customer_ID
    -- Handle null
    OR COALESCE([SOURCE].Customer_Email,'') <> COALESCE([TARGET].Customer_Email,'')
    -- Handle null
    OR COALESCE([SOURCE].Customer_Notes,'') <> COALESCE([TARGET].Customer_Notes,'')
)
```

However I would add duplicate detection in the logging trigger rather than here.

Note: The [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) explain all this and more.

Comment: one last question, How can I update only the columns that are being modified.. in that case, we can take off the `OrderNumber, Product_Id & Cutomer_Id` columns for the Update set because we are always verifying match for those columns inorder to get into Update logic. But, how can I only update the columns `(Customer_ID, Customer_Email, Customer_Notes)` that are being modified instead of updating them with or without changes to original values in the existing record. The reason for this question is I have created a history table for the `CustomOrderReqs` table and dont want to create duplicate

Comment: Sorry my bad. As we are checking for the Match inorder to Update an existing record, we can remove the columns `OrderNumber, Product_Id & Cutomer_Id` from the Update statement, as follows.` WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET  [TARGET].Purchase_amt = @Purchase_amt, [TARGET].Customer_ID = [SOURCE].Customer_ID, [TARGET].Customer_Email = [SOURCE].Customer_Email , [TARGET].Customer_Notes = [SOURCE].Customer_Notes WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN `

Comment: But, I would only want to update the columns `(Customer_ID, Customer_Email, Customer_Notes`, that are being modified only, instead of updating them everytime when the Update logic hits

Comment: You can Ignore the `@negItem`, it suppose to be `@Product_Id`

Comment: I have created an History or Log table that trace down the changes and I dont want to log records without any changes to the columns that are being updated